# From getstream Total unseen count not getting more than 100

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

We have a Notification Feeds type of timeline. We are using Nodejs(stream-js) package.

We can only get unseen count maximum of 100. Can we get total unseen count even though it is more than 100. We just want the overall total count.
How can we get this? Is there any separate API for getting all unseen count? Can you please guide us?

```
feed = client.feed('activity_you_notify', '3');
Promise.resolve(feed.get()).then(function (value) {

}, function (err) {

});
```

From the response, we always get 100. Shouldn't we get 101, 102, 103 unseen counts from "unseen": 100?

Can you please guide us?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So the feed.get() API call is limited to 100 records. What you're going to need to do is paginate your response. Here's some information on how you can achieve this

https://getstream.io/docs/#retrieve

Stephen

Comment: No, i want total unseen count with single api call. You are telling me to fetch all page and aggregate the count. i want to get all unseen count with single api call.